# How to create a variable number of layer in MLP

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Recently I am working with Tensorflow. I was exploring how to implement multilayer Perceptron in Tensorflow.

I came through a lot of tutorial in online. most of them utilize one or two hidden layer. A simple example is taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/vinhkhuc/e53a70f9e5c3f55852b0)

```
def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2):
    """
    Forward-propagation.
    IMPORTANT: yhat is not softmax since TensorFlow's 
    softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() does that internally.
    """
    h    = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))  # The \sigma function
    yhat = tf.matmul(h, w_2)  # The \varphi function
    return yhat

X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size])
y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size])

# Weight initializations
w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_size))
w_2 = init_weights((h_size, y_size))

# Forward propagation
out    = forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2)
```

In this code, there is one hidden layer. Now I am wondering if I wanted to build a variable number of layered fully connected neural net.

Assume a list **h_archi=[100 150 100 50]** where each of the value represents a number of neuron in i'th layer(in this case the total number of layer is 4). So for variable number of layer implementation, I coded the following ugly code,

```
    emb_vec = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([vocabulary_size, EMBEDDING_DIM]), name="emb_vec")

    tot_layer = len(h_archi)
    op = np.zeros(tot_layer+1)
    hid_rep = np.zeros(tot_layer+1)
    bias = np.zeros(tot_layer+1)

    op[0] = tf.matmul(x, emb_vec)

    for idx,tot_neu in enumerate(h_archi):
        assert( tot_neu > 0 )
        layer_no = idx+1
        r,c = op[layer_no-1].get_shape()
        hid_rep[layer_no] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([c,tot_neu]),name="hid_{0}_{1}".format(layer_no-1,layer_no))
        bias[layer_no] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([tot_neu]), name="bias_{0}".format(layer_no))
        op[layer_no] = tf.add(tf.matmul(op[layer_no-1],hid_rep[layer_no]),bias[layer_no])

    r,c = op[tot_layer].get_shape()
    last_layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([c,output_size]),name="hid_{0}_{1}".format(tot_layer,"last_layer"))
    bias_last = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_size]), name="bias_last")
    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(op[tot_layer],last_layer))
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(output)
```

This code is completely wrong as tensorflow does not support assignment operation. So what could be the proper way to design such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this instead of your loop:

```
    last_layer=x
    for idx,tot_neu in enumerate(h_archi):
        assert( tot_neu > 0 )
        layer_no = idx+1
        r,c = last_layer.get_shape()
        weights_ = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([c,tot_neu]),name="hid_{0}_{1}".format(layer_no-1,layer_no))
        bias_ = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([tot_neu]), name="bias_{0}".format(layer_no))
        last_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(last_layer,weights_),bias_)
    r,c = last_layer.get_shape()
```

If you need to access the intermediary tensors (biases, weights, layers, etc), you could just store them at each step in a list for instance

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.